# Using Eclipse CDT and Clearcase

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, eclipse-cdt

I recently joined a large C++ project that where the codebase is housed in Clearcase. The primarly build system is make, which is also in Clearcase. The builds are unwieldy and long, so I would like to use the Clearcase plugin for Eclipse to select a small subset of files for an Eclipse CDT project I can use as an alternative build system for active development and debugging.

Is there a robust way to do this? The Eclipse setup is Helios SR2 running on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, one can create a project by way of File > New > "Makefile Project with Existing Code". The "Import Existing Code" dialog appears where one can enter a root folder path.

Answer (score 3):

First, a general advice: use snapshot views, not dynamic views, for your compilation, especially if you need to access (for linking purposes for instance) large binaries: the compilation will be faster.

Plus, in a snapshot view, with its loading rules, you will select the subset of files you actually need to see and work on.

The other way to fasten a compilation (if you haven't the need to access large binaries), is to use *dynamic view* this time, but with `clearmake` instead of `make`, allowing for ClearCase to record the **DO** (Derived Object): see "[ClearCase Build Concepts](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_build_windows.doc/clearcase_build_concepts.htm)"

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have been using snapshot views. My question has more to do with how to use the Eclipse project/build system while just the source is under Clearcase version control using the Eclipse Clearcase plugin.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I am not aware of a particular process: the makefile will read the source files (whether or not they are under version control, and even if they aren't checked out), and it will produce the obj.